# Jenkins: Groovy: How to update queue when Node label changed

Tags: groovy, jenkins, label

I have a job running Integration Test on Slaves with label `"IntegrationTest"`. 
When the Job started, I use `Node.setLabelString(String)` to modify the Slave Label from IntegrationTest to `"_out_IntegrationTest"`, in order to block this slave from running next round integration test, because we need to revert this slave to clean environment before integration test.

The problem is that the following Integration Test job in queue still can take this slave to run even though its label was set to `"_out_IntegrationTest"` by `Node.setLabelString(String)`.

I am not sure the Label is modified, but queue is not aware of this.

When I modify slave Label to `"_out_IntegrationTest"` manually from Web UI, the Integration Test Job will not run on this slave.

When Slave Label modified by `Node.setLabelString(String)`, the Job still can run on it.

Note:
`Queue.maintain()` is called after `Node.setLabelString(String)` invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation in my workplace where I need to reboot a slave after running a job. So I have a separate job that reboots the slave it runs on. As the first build step in the main job, I request to schedule a parameterized build of the reboot job, using the parameter "build on the same node". The reboot job is configured with a very high priority (via [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin)) so that it will be guaranteed to be the next job run on that node. Then I have the other build steps of the main job to perform its required tasks.

When the main job finishes, the reboot job comes in and reboots the slave - here you could perform the reversion of your slave to the clean environment.

[image]